# How to set a dynamic URL in a parent template in Django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am using a parent template in my django project for the navigation menu. In the navigation menu I have a  tag that has an href that will point to the current week of NFL games. I want to set this dynamically based on the current time. I am looking for something I can set in my parent template (base.html) so that I don't have to repeat code in every child template in my_app.

The model I am using for the Week is:

```
class Week(models.Model):
  WeekID = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
  Week = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(18)])
  SeasonID = models.ForeignKey('Season', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
  TimeStart = models.DateTimeField()
  TimeEnd = models.DateTimeField()
  
  def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.SeasonID.Year} Season Week {self.Week}"
```

My parent template code is:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles.css' %}" />
    <title>{% block pageTitle %} {%endblock%}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navigation">
      <ul class="navigation__list">
        <li class="navigation__item">
          {% for week in current_week %}
            <a href="/my_app/week/{{week.WeekID}" class="navigation__link">Current Week</a>
          {% endfor %}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>{% block content %} {% endblock %}</main>
  </body>
</html>
```

The view that I need to get the necessary data:

```
def current_week(request):
  current_time = datetime.now()
  current_week = Week.objects.filter(TimeStart_lt=current_time, TimeEnd_gt=current_time)
  print(current_week)
  return render(request, 'base.html', context={'current_week': current_week})
```

The structure of my project is:

```
my_project
    my_app
        templates
            my_app
                example_child_template.html
    my_project
        urls.py
        settings.py
    templates
        base.html
    views.py***
    urls.py***
```

my_project urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('my_app/', include('my_app.urls'))
]
```

My questions are:

1. Can I use the 'current_week' view with a parent template (base.html) based on where it is in my project directory?
2. (Edited) Where would I put views.py and urls.py relative to the base.html template? Are the files with *** the right spot to put them?
3. How would I connect the urls.py*** in the project directory to the urls.py that is in my_project, which contains the path for admin and my_app?

Comment: I would recommend to follow one of the avaiable django tutorials as you seem to be struggling with several of the basic concepts of a django app. Also it is difficult to help here as you use changing names through your post for "main" "base" "parent" "mastermain" ... templates. Maybe edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: urls.py is the entry point for any request to a django app, so yes it is necessary. urls.py links an url to a view. In the view you choose which template to render.

Comment: where django searches for templates is defined in settings.py -> TEMPLATES  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/templates/

Comment: @Razenstein With the parent template(base.html) being where it is in the project directory, would views.py*** and urls.py*** be in the right place? And if so, how would I connect them to urlpatterns in my_project urls.py? Would the correct way be: path('', include('urls')?

Answer (score 0):

If you want current_week accesible in context of every template (including base.html) and don't want to add them manualy in every view function i would go with context proccesors.

you need to create function that returns dict with 'current_week' key it's like yours view function:

```
def current_week(request):
  current_time = datetime.now()
  current_week = Week.objects.filter(TimeStart_lt=current_time, TimeEnd_gt=current_time)

  return {'current_week': current_week}
```

then in `settings.py` you need to link your function in `context_proccesrs` :

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'appname.filename.current_week',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Buy doing so you make `'current_week'` accesible in evry template of your project. I advise to think of some sort of cache inside this function beacuse it will hit database evry request.

Comment: Would using a session variable work for caching? If the session variable is null, call to the database, if it is not null then return the session variable.

Answer (score 0):

**add question 2):**  a typical django structure would be:

```
my_project
    my_app1
        templates
            my_app1
                example_child_template.html
        urls.py
        models.py
        views.py
    my_app2
        templates
            my_app2
                example_child_template.html
        urls.py
        models.py
        views.py
    my_project          # this is kind of the "entry point" for all requests
        wsgi.py         # your http server need to know this!!
        urls.py         # settings.py->ROOT_URLCONF points here!
        settings.py
    templates
        base.html       # optional if you like, can also be in an app
```

so a view would always make part of an app.

**add question 1):**

Where are the templates?  The django render function uses the resources listed in seettings.py->TEMPLATES like

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                 ....
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

the basic interesting things are 'DIRS' and 'APP_DIRS'.

1. 'DIRS': if you want, for all views, that templates are also searched for in 'my_project/templates' or 'my_project/myfolder' then you have to add:

```
        'DIRS': ['templates', 'myfolder'],
```

2. 'APP_DIRS': if you want, for all apps (listed in seettings.py-> INSTALLED_APPS !!), that templates are searched for in the standard folder my_app/templates then you have to add:

```
        'APP_DIRS': True,
```

So if you want to render base.html in ANY view just put something like:

```
def my_view(request):
    ...
    context = ...
    return render(request, 'base.html', context)
```

and django template processor will find base.html because of 'DIRS'.

If you want to make base.html a part of your example_child_template then the render process would render child which in turn extends base:

```
def my_view(request):
    ...
    context = ...
    return render(request, 'my_app2/example_child_template.html', context)
```

(remember: my_app2.. is part of templates path because of 'APP_DIRS')

and inside child:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block pageTitle %} ... {%endblock%}

{% block content %}  ... {% endblock %}
```

**add question 3):**
a request will be go this way:

```
http server
   my_project->wsgi.py
      my_project->urls.py  ...# include my_app/urls.py
         my_app->urls.py
             my_app->views.py
                 do something in the view
                 return a http response (e.g. render html template)
```

wsgi.py reads settings.py and looks for ROOT_URLCONF like in your case should be:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'my_project.urls'
```

then every request from the server will be routed via that root urls.py. From there(!) you go down  via includes to your apps->urls.py

**Theoretically** you could leave that urls.py*** were it is and declare it as root like this:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'
```

and inside urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('my_project.urls'))
]
```

BUT: that is an extra step and not a django like standard structure.

Comment: Thank you! This explains a lot. I was reading the docs and couldn't work everything out in my head.